# How to mock cxfbean call in Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I've got route that calls cxfbean:

```
.to("cxfbean:reservationService")
```

Tried mock this in my test with

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:reservationService")
MockEndpoint reservationSystemMock;

@BeforeMethod
private void setUpContext() throws Exception
{
     context.getRouteDefinition( "send.to.res.svc.endpoint" ).adviceWith(
         context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
         @Override
         public void configure() throws Exception         
         {
              interceptSendToEndpoint("cxfbean:reservationService") 
                                      .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                                      .to("mock:reservationService");
         }
     });
}
```

Also tried mock with `weaveByToString( "**reservationService" ).replace().to( "mock:reservationService" );`. In both cases I get:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: reservationService
```

I'd like to test my route without cxf bean instantiation. I'm using CamelTestSupport class as parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to mock cxfbean endpoint with `weaveByToString( "To[cxfbean:reservationService]" )`:

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:reservationService")
protected MockEndpoint reservationSystemMock;

@BeforeMethod
private void setUpContext() throws Exception
{
    context.getRouteDefinition( "send.to.res.svc.endpoint" ).adviceWith(
        context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                weaveByToString( "To[cxfbean:reservationService]" )
                .replace().to( "mock:reservationService" );
            }
        });
}
```

Also seems that we can peek necessary expression for `weaveByToString` using `context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).toString()` in debug watcher

Answer (score 0):

Remember to turn on advice-with on your test class. If you use those annotations, then add `@UseAdviceWith` to the class.

And then start the camel context **after** you have advised, which

- http://camel.apache.org/spring-testing.html
- http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html